# How to prove that the \$3\$ nodes have the same potentials?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, voltage

The question of symmetry.
[image]
The each resistor has the same resistance(given by \$r\$).

Why a current doesn't flows between the each endpoints of the middle \$2\$ resistors?

The text book only states of it with "symmetry of middle vertical line".

Proving that node \$(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)\$ have the same potentials is enough to show that the above claim is correct I think.

Can anyone tell me some hint(s) to prove the sameness of the potentials? so that I can deduce it in my own.

Comment: Balanced Wheatstone Bridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine node A is at +V for some voltage V and node B is at -V.

There is symmetry about the middle vertical line, so the voltage at 3,2 at 2,2 and at 1,2 is 0V.

Therefore no current flows through the vertical resistors and they can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to approach that circuit from a voltage perspective than a current perspective.

In the abstraction of the current, let's assume Node A is 5V and B is 0V.

You can first ignore the two central resistors and calculate the node voltage, given the circuit is symmetric, the central nodes would be half of that, so 2.5V.

Given the voltage is the same on all the central nodes, then no current flows, thus confirming we can safely ignore them.

The two central resistors can be ignored.

It is then easy to calculate the current of each node.

Comment: The question in essence asks "why can the two central resistors be ignored?", I don't see how just stating it again as fact helps.